# How do I get an email alert when my paper is cited?

Tags: citations, online-resource

I recently published a paper in a journal which does not offer a notification system to send email alerts when a paper is cited. The journal is a well known and has a high-impact factor in my field. Are there free services which can automatically send me an email alert when my paper is cited in another publication?

Comment: Scopus does this, too, if your university has a subscription. It will give you citations from published papers only, though, which means significantly fewer than Google Scholar and significantly later in time.

Comment: Academia.edu must offer this.  Even though I didn's sign up for them, I keep getting emails from them like "Gerald Edgar" was mentioned by "....", with a link *View your mentions*.

Answer (score 57, accepted):

You can set up an [alert on Google scholar](http://scholar.google.com/scholar_alerts?view_op=list_alerts&hl=en) that will do exactly what you want. From Google's [help page](http://scholar.google.com/intl/en-US/scholar/help.html#alerts):

> **How do I get notified when a particular paper is cited?**
>
> Search for the title of your paper, e.g., "Anti de Sitter space and
> holography"; click on the "Cited by" link at the bottom of the search
> result; and then click on the envelope icon in the left sidebar of the
> search results page.

An even more effective way can be to set up a google scholar [citation profile](http://scholar.google.com/intl/en-US/scholar/citations.html) and select "Follow new citations" from the appropriate checkbox in the "Follow"/"Following" menu of your own profile.

Comment: Last sentence instructions seem a little out of date. I added a new answer with how to set up the automatic notifications for all citations on your articles.

Answer (score 17):

The top answer mentions setting up a "google scholar citation profile" to get notified automatically when any of your articles are cited. Those instructions may be out of date, so here's how to do it **as of June 2018:**

1. Go to your own google scholar profile (you probably have to set one up first)
2. Click the blue "Follow" button
3. Select one or more of the three checkboxes: "New articles in my profile", "New citations to my articles", "Recommended articles".

If you like, you can also subscribe to these categories for other researchers' pages (probably "new articles" is the most useful in that case).

All of these email notifications can be listed and managed, along with your keyword alerts, in your Scholar Alerts page, which can be found at https://scholar.google.com/scholar_alerts?view_op=list_alerts&hl=en.

Answer (score 0):

Another option would be [ResearchGate](https://www.researchgate.net/) . It a bit like facebook for academia (e.g., you can additionally follow people and get alerts when they publish new research). It's free, so you can give it a try.

Comment: And you get a lot of free spam, too!

Comment: I have used ResearchGate to find papers that I either cannot find elsewhere or that my library does not have a subscription for. That's about the only use it has. The "discussions" on the site are full of crackpot theories.

Comment: @MarcClaesen I don't know if ResearchGate is responsible for some of the spam I receive (it might be), or do you mean all the messages from RG itself? You can deactivate the notifications that you don't want.

Comment: @Moriarty Don't get me wrong, I'm not a RG fanboy! It's true, the discussions (and the ranking system) are IMHO often not very helpful. But I the citation notifications and the paper request system can be helpful.

Comment: I'm not even signed up for research gate and get a lot of spam emails from them. I would not recommend a company who works like this.

Answer (score 0):

If you work in a fields whose main journals are indexed by the ["Astrophysics Data System"](https://ui.adsabs.harvard.edu/) (e.g., astronomy, astrophysics, or space science), you can use the [ADS Citation Bot.](https://github.com/hippke/adsbot)  This bot will send you either an email or a tweet  when a new citation to one of your papers has appeared.